# Clone container for re-use without all events and elements attached later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a container div as a jQuery object that I use to switch images around in in a class(javascript object). At some point the user may decide to reset that container.

Instead of removing all the HTML elements and all the click/drag/resize listeners that I've attached to that container to reset it I thought it would be a good idea to clone the container in my construct function so I can re-get it when I'm resetting as such:

```
this.container = container;
//keep an original in case it needs to be reset
this.originalContainer = container.clone();
```

**method for resetting: **

```
redrawImageFromOriginal: function (newImage) {
    this.image = newImage;
    this.container = this.originalContainer;
    this.placeImage(this.getImageWidth(), this.getImageHeight(), this.getImgX(), this.getImgY());
},
```

Obviously, when I do this I lose the scope of the container I was working with. So `this.container` becomes something different than the `this.container` I've been working with until now.

Now, My question in short is: How can I get the container back to it's default behavior(Or lack of it) so I can rebuild it as I please afterwards.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle with example?

Comment: Since there's a whole framework attached to it and a few 1000's lines of codes I really can't. I was hoping the question was clear enough to 'catch my drift'. I'm sorry! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clone data and events both while cloning, please follow below code:

`this.container = container;`

//keep an original in case it needs to be reset

```
this.originalContainer = container.clone(true, true);

clone( [dataAndEvents] [, allDataAndEvents] )
```

dataAndEvents: A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements. The default value is false.

allDataAndEvents: A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. By default its value matches the first argument's value (which defaults to false).

Hope it works for you :)